# Python: индексы

Tags: python, python-2.x

Допустим, у меня есть список

```
g = [123, 321, 222, 111]
for i in g:
    print i
    print 'a=%s, b=%s' % (i, '?')
```

Мне надо перегнать все значения по списку и чтобы "а" принимало значение "i", а "b" - значение "i-1", то есть номер индекса перед ним.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Магия, вторая попытка!

```
g = [123, 321, 222, 111]
previous = None
for i in g:
    print 'a=%s, b=%s' % (i, previous)
    previous = i
```

Comment: Да ладно...
Все на столько елементарно... пора мне отдохнуть )
Большое спасибо, а то я уже голову сломал)))

Answer (score 4):

Если уж зашла речь об индексах, то такой вариант:

```
g = [123, 321, 222, 111]
for i, a in enumerate(g):
    if i>0:
        print 'a=%s, b=%s' % (a, g[i-1])
```

Вывод:

```
a=321, b=123
a=222, b=321
a=111, b=222
```

Если убрать условие, то для первого элемента "предыдущим" будет последний элемент:

```
g = [123, 321, 222, 111]
for i, a in enumerate(g):
    print 'a=%s, b=%s' % (a, g[i-1])
```

Вывод:

```
a=123, b=111
a=321, b=123
a=222, b=321
a=111, b=222
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def gen_pairs(lst):
    for i in xrange(len(lst) - 1):
        yield lst[i], lst[i + 1]

for i, j in gen_pairs([123, 321, 222, 111]):
    print('%i %i' % (i, j))
```